# How do I write a POST request in JSON to post a new product?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a WebAPI. I have used Entity framework to make an SQL database via the C# code my friend and I have written. Our product table in the SQL Database is based on the following code:

```
public class Product
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "Product Number")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }


    [Range(0, 99999)]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int MarketID { get; set; }


    public Market Market { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductAssignment> ProductAssignments { get; set; }

}
```

When we run our solution and open up Postman to make a post request we are not sure how the JSON should be written. So far we have written:

```
{
"ProductID": 1234,
  "ProductName": "Testproduct",
  "Price": 10,
  "MarketID": 4321,
  "Market": 
    {
       "MarketID": 1111,
       "Name": "Market1",
       "Budget": 1.5,
       "StartDate": 2019-11-28,
       "ProductGuideID": 123
    }
    "Subscriptions":
    {
        "SubscriptionId":1234,
        "ProductId": 1234,
        "CustomerID": 1234,
        "CustomerLoyalty": "A"
    }
    "ProductAssignments"
    {
        "ProductGuideId": 1234,
        "ProductID": 1234
    }
}
```

The problem is that we do not know how to write the JSON for Market, Subscriptions and ProductAssignments.

What should we write in JSON to POST a new Product?

EDIT:

Market class:

```
public class Market
    {
        public int MarketID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public int? ProductGuideID { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public ProductGuide Administrator { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Subscription:

```
 public enum CustomerLoyalty
{
    A, B, C, D, F
}
public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Loyalty not set")]
    public CustomerLoyalty? CustomerLoyalty { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

ProductAssignment:

```
public class ProductAssignment
{
    public int ProductGuideID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public ProductGuide ProductGuide { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
ProductsController.cs:

```
namespace VitekAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Products")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BusinessContext _context;

    public ProductsController(BusinessContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Products
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetProducts()
    {
        return await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Products/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return product;
    }

    // PUT: api/Products/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutProduct(int id, Product product)
    {
        if (id != product.ProductID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Products
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(product);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ProductExists(product.ProductID))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = product.ProductID }, product);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Products/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Products.Remove(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return product;
    }

    private bool ProductExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Products.Any(e => e.ProductID == id);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Link to our github repository: https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

Comment: It depends on the Market, Subscription and ProductAssigment classes - which you didn't post in your question...

Comment: @PeterSchneider I have added the relevant code for Market, Subscription and ProductAssignment

Comment: I have downloaded your project on github and try to reproduce your issue.But it seems that you have uploaded a MVC project instead of Web Api.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the notations of JSON types [here](https://www.w3resource.com/JSON/structures.php).

Given your product class the JSON Notation would look something like this:

```
{
  "ProductID": 1234,
  "ProductName": "Testproduct",
  "Price": 10,
  "MarketID": 4321,
  "Market": 
    {
       "MarketID": 1111,
       "Name": "Market1",
       "Budget": 1.5,
       "StartDate": 2019-11-28,
       "ProductGuideID": 123
    }
    // All your other custom objects
}
```

Comment: Thankyou but it did not work. I get a 404 not found error when I try to POST it. I have updated the postman pic in the post to show it with what you wrote.

Comment: Could you show your POST method in your controller?

Comment: Yes I just updated the post to show the POST method in my ProducstController.cs file.

Comment: It's quite long... you may consider [adding swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to your webapi.. the generated documentation shows every request with example values...

Comment: @CodingStudent how is the Route defined in your controller?
If you get a 404 you're not posting to the correct url.

Comment: @Zalhera The following is my routing in the ProductsController.cs:     [Route("api/Products")]
    [ApiController] and in my Startup.cs file in my Configure method I have the following line including in the method: app.UseRouting();

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're getting a 404
In my test project the post to the controller works as intended.

Comment: My friend and I are just working on getting the API project up on github. I will link the repository once it is done. We are having problems with getting a 2nd project in the same solution up in the same repository as the 1st project. Will update soon.

Comment: @Zalhera. We have put all our code up on github. Will try out your solution now. Thankyou.

Comment: @Zalhera I have updated the post with the JSON we have so far. It still returns a 404 not found error. I think the problem might be that inside our market class we have an instance of a ProductGuide and also a collection of Products which we have not mentioned in the JSON? the Collection of Subscriptions and ProductAssignment also contains instances of other classes and ICollections. We obviously cant keep writing them out as we would be going in a loop and keep writing a product again and again...

Comment: @CodingStudent I still think you're having a problem with the controller mapping.
If you would post incorrect json to your url you should receive a 50x error, because the server is expecting a different body. 
Could you link the github page to your project?

Comment: @Zalhera I have updated the post with my productscontroller.cs code. I am not sure how to post JSON to my url will do some research on it now. The following is a link to my github. It is the VitekAPI project that I am working on https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

Comment: EDIT: My repository is not working properly will write as soon as I have it solved

Comment: @Zalhera the repository is working know. I was just told that it is working on another guys computer and I only have the opening repository up problem locally

Comment: @CodingStudent I cloned your repository and my json successfully to localhost:port/api/products (I used the VitekAPI project)
So the json notation is correct but apperently you posted to the wrong url